# How do I check the total number of closed tags using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The code below checks whether there more than one open html tag ,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


invalid = """<html>
<html>

</html>
</html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(invalid, 'html.parser')
print len(soup.find_all("html"))  # prints 2

valid = """<html>
</html></html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(valid, 'html.parser')
print len(soup.find_all("html"))  # prints 1
```

But How to check whether there is more than one closed html tag?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `BeautifulSoup`, because it's specifically a *tag soup* parser. It cleans up mis-matched open and close tags for you, that's part of the point.

Instead, use the parser that BeautifulSoup uses. There's a standard one in Python, called `HTMLParser` in Python2 and `html.parser` in Python3. If you've read the BeautifulSoup documentation you know that others are available, such as `lxml` or `html5lib`.

So for example:

```
import html.parser

class Parser(html.parser.HTMLParser):
    count = 0
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag == 'html':
            self.count += 1

parser = Parser()
parser.feed('<html></html><!-- </html> --></html>')
parser.close()
print(parser.count)
```

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: If I have 3 <h3> tags in my html file. How can I check the string available in first and third one?

Comment: @Jusrock: what part of that do you need help with? I can see from your question that you already know about `soup.find_all`.